# How to layout the half part of a view to root view using Layout XML file?

Tags: android, android-layout

If I want to merely layout half part of a view (as illustrated by the red box in below figure) to the root-view, in other word, I don't want to show the right part of the view in device screen. How can I do that by using android layout xml file?

[image]

Comment: that depends on how you did perform the right over expansion of the red View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below solution

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linMiddle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

You have give `runtime twice width` to `linMiddle`

Comment: I tried your solution, it works. Here is my test code: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.qihoo.uitest.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>